# active directory migration problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain, migration

We are migrating a domain into ours; for this example domaina is the existing domain, and domainb is the new acquisition.  domainb is to become a sub-domain of ours.  ADMT3.2 works great - we have migrated users and computers as well as some member servers. My question is this:

The old domain has some users with the same names as in our domain.  How can i migrate these users in and not to conflict with my exsisting users?  (e.g johnsmit@domaina.com and johnsmit@domainb.com)

Answer (score 3):

Tell ADMT not to migrate conflicting accounts. Then migrate them and let ADMT rename conflicting accounts by adding a pre- or suffix. Now you can identify the easily in the target domain and change them if you want to.